# is it possible civicrm templates_c files to be stored under the server /tmp folder?

Tags: wordpress, templates, cache

Has someone tried it? On a 1st try I've noticed extensions stop working.
For example if I set define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', '/tmp/civicrm/templates_c/'); would it work? (instead of ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/)
I need it for a civicrm install under WPEng hosting where they do not allow php script to write into another php script within wordpress. Hence re-generating the templates_c files is a problem.

Comment: If they're restrictive they may also have php's open_basedir set that might not allow access to /tmp. In any case the web server (apache or wwwrun or whatever user) would need write access to that folder, so check that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use WPEng hosting for civicrm.